# Script to Find a registry key with wildcard and remove it

Tags: powershell

I am trying to clean out old Firefox registry entries that are causing our vulnerability scanner to freak out.


The script I am using is:

```
New-PSDrive HKU Registry HKEY_USERS
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKU:\*\Software\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox*" |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSPath |
  ForEach-Object {Remove-PsPath -Path $_ -WhatIf}
```

but it fails. I know my issue is in the last section: `ForEach-Object {Remove-PsPath -Path $_ -WhatIf}` as I can run the other part of the script and get my expected data returns.

The Keys in the registry I want to remove are located in the `HKU\%%%randoms SID%%%\Software\Mozilla` path.  They are:

```
HKU\%%%randoms SID%%%\Software\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox
HKU\%%%randoms SID%%%\Software\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox ESR
```

I want the script to remove the entire key and all the subkeys.  What am I doing wrong in my script?

Comment: What is the error (or erroneous output/action) that you are seeing?

Comment: Have you tried `Get-Item` and piping it directly to `Remove-Item`?

Comment: The term 'Remove-PsPath' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.

Answer (score 0):

`Remove-PsPath` doesn't exist, as far as I can tell. But it all can be reduced to this:

```
New-PSDrive HKU Registry HKEY_USERS
Remove-Item "HKU:\*\Software\Mozilla\*Firefox*" -Recurse -WhatIf
```

And of course, remove `-WhatIf` once you're sure you want to run it.

Also note that I've added an extra wildcard before *Firefox* because I noticed on my test machine that registry key was simply called *Firefox* and not *Mozilla Firefox*. This'll still target your original registry keys.